# wso2esb library not loaded when using spring

Tags: spring, wso2-esb

I have a problem when setting up spring on wso2carbob ESB 4.8.0

this is the code I run

```
public MyMediator(){
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringApplicationContext.class);

org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext msgContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) msgCntx)
                .getAxis2MessageContext();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> headersMap = (Map<String, String>) msgContext
                .getProperty(org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.TRANSPORT_HEADERS);
...
}
@Autowired 
private MyObject myObject;
```

and this is the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/synapse/core/axis2/Axis2MessageContext
    at eu.dedalus.x1v1.policymanager.pep.mediator.PepMediator.mediate(PepMediator.java:57)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.spring.SpringMediator.mediate(SpringMediator.java:94)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:459)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:279)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

If I comment out this line:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringApplicationContext.class);
```

everything runs well, and the class *org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext* is loaded fine.

I put my jar under repository/components/lib, and used the default spring version, that comes with the ESB, this is the maven dependency, in the wso2 repository:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws.wso2</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring.framework</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.wso2v1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

In this case my goal is to get the http headers of the message. 
But in a more generic scenario is to use a library that is under plugins with spring annotations. 
How can I do to view that class?

Answer (score 0):

to use annotation base spring configuration you need to have spring aop.jar file. however wso2 esb spring mediator does not support for annotation base configuration. you need to go with xml based configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible, but not in the class constructor, I think this is because the *osgi framework classloading structure*.

Wso2 instatiate a bunch of all mediator you declare, but I think it does that in a phase of *system init* so not all classes are already loaded, or maybe when it does the *initialization* it use a different class loader.. ..these are only suppositions.

However you can create an application context in the *mediate* method as in this sample:

```
 public MyObject myObject;

 public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringApplicationContext.class);
    myObject = context.getBean(MyObject.class);


}
```

That's not really performing because the method *mediate* is always called at runtime, so my-really-not-clean solution is to declare *MyObject* as **static** like this:

```
 public static MyObject myObject;

 public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {
    if(myObject == null){
       ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringApplicationContext.class);
       myObject = context.getBean(MyObject.class);
    }


}
```

So now I have a *singleton* of **myObject**, and that's exactly what I wanted and what spring does